# Jquery, Ajax success message appears only once onclick and the second time it did not display

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After clicking the form the data is successfully processed and I get the green success message with out refreshing the page. However while I am on the page and try to submit form again, the success message would not show up but the form reset itself. What should I do to get the success message every time with no refreshing the page?

By the way, if I refresh the page then the success message will be display again.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#TestForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"post.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#resultback').addClass("alert alert-success").html('Your data has sent succesfully! ');
                $('#TestForm').trigger("reset");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#resultback').fadeOut('slow'); }, 3000);
            },
            error: function (data) {  $('#status').html(status);
            }
        })
    })
    $('#TestForm').reset;
})
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: is there any error shows on the console?

Comment: can you edit your post to add the html you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `$('#resultback').fadeOut` is completed, your message will receive a `display: none;` style. So, after you put content in `#resultback`, just do a `$('#resultback').show();`

Check it out in http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 0):

Please show "resultback" element before fading out.
$('#resultback').show()

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works just fine. You are certainly the man of today! :-)